# LaTeX error with footnotes

Tags: footnotes, babel, spanish

This is the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}

        \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
 CaDeNTiA CDNs/DTNs sobre Android
        \end{minipage}

        \LARGE Documento n\sptext{o}3 -- \textbf{Anexo}

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage

\section{Convenciones estil\'isticas}

Cuando no ha sido posible escribir un comando en una sola línea se ha escrito unque le indica al terminal que el comando continúa en la siguiente línea. Si bien ha habido algunos casos como, por ejemplo, al escribir URLs largas, donde no se ha escrito el símbo.\footnote{hola}

asfdsf a\footnote{dfasdf}

\end{document}
```

Which gives this error on the 2nd page:

[image]

It can be seen that something in the titlepage spoils the footnote number. I can remove the `minipage` or the `\sptext` command (related with Spanish `babel`), or even the `\LARGE` to solve it but, I would need all in my real final document.

Comment: How do you compile your document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code for `\es@sptext` in `spanish.ldf` relies on `\f@size`, `\sf@size` and `\ssf@size` that are updated only when `\check@mathfonts` is issued; this macro computes those sizes based on the current font size. Just adding this macro to the definition of `\ex@sptext` seems to cure the issue:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article} 

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\makeatletter
\def\es@sptext#1{{%
  \es@orddot
  \check@mathfonts % <------ ADDED
  \sbox\z@{8}\dimen@\ht\z@
  \csname S@\f@size\endcsname
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \def\noexpand\@tempc{#1}%
    \lowercase{\def\noexpand\@tempb{#1}}}%
  \@tempa
  \ifx\@tempb\@tempc
    \fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont
    \advance\dimen@ -1.15ex
  \else
    \fontsize\ssf@size\z@\selectfont
    \advance \dimen@ -1.5ex
  \fi
  \math@fontsfalse
  \raise\dimen@\hbox{#1}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}


\begin{titlepage}

        \begin{minipage}{0.8\textwidth}
 CaDeNTiA CDNs/DTNs sobre Android
        \end{minipage}

        \LARGE Documento n\sptext{o}3 -- \textbf{Anexo}

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage

\section{Convenciones estil\'isticas}

Cuando no ha sido posible escribir un comando en una sola línea se ha escrito unque le 
indica al terminal que el comando continúa en la siguiente línea. Si bien ha habido 
algunos casos como, por ejemplo, al escribir URLs largas, donde no se ha escrito el 
símbo.\footnote{hola}

asfdsf a\footnote{dfasdf}

\end{document}
```

The file `spanish.ldf` has two definitions for `\es@sptext`; the one used with LaTeX2e is in the “true” branch.

Here is the title page:

[image]

And here is the second page:

[image]

---

Why does the second footnote mark appear with the correct size? Because TeX uses math mode for typesetting the first footnote mark in the footnote, so after having set it in the text; thus the `\check@mathfonts` command is executed as always when math mode is entered.

This is a bug that should be reported.

Comment: Thansk, If I find a bug like this, how can it be reported? I try to find the email of the developer in CTAN http://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel-spanish but I find nothing

Comment: I have used http://latex-project.org/bugs-upload.html

Comment: http://www.latex-project.org/cgi-bin/ltxbugs2html?category=LaTeX&responsible=anyone&state=anything&keyword=&pr=latex%2F4351&search=

Comment: OK, I've deleted my answer.